# What's the difference between Lucene StandardAnalyzer and EnglishAnalyzer?

Tags: lucene

I'm working on indexing tweets that are in English using Lucene 4.3, however I'm not sure which Analyzer to use. What's the difference between Lucene StandardAnalyzer and EnglishAnalyzer?

Also I tried to test the StandardAnalyzer with this text: "XY&Z Corporation - xyz@example.com". The output is: [xy] [z] [corporation] [xyz] [example.com], however I thought the output will be: [XY&Z] [Corporation] [xyz@example.com]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the source.  Generally, analyzers are pretty readable.  You just need to look into `CreateComponents` method to see the Tokenizer and Filters being used by it:

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, source);
    // prior to this we get the classic behavior, standardfilter does it for us.
    if (matchVersion.onOrAfter(Version.LUCENE_31))
      result = new EnglishPossessiveFilter(matchVersion, result);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, result);
    result = new StopFilter(matchVersion, result, stopwords);
    if(!stemExclusionSet.isEmpty())
      result = new KeywordMarkerFilter(result, stemExclusionSet);
    result = new PorterStemFilter(result);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
 }
```

Whereas, `StandardAnalyzer` is just a `StandardTokenizer`, `StandardFilter`, `LowercaseFilter`, and `StopFilter`.  `EnglishAnalyzer` rolls in an `EnglishPossesiveFilter`, `KeywordMarkerFilter`, and `PorterStemFilter`.

Mainly, the EnglishAnalyzer rolls in some English stemming enhancements, which should work well for plain English text.

For StandardAnalyzer, really the only assumption I'm aware of that ties it directly to English analysis, is the default stopword set, which is of course, just a default and can be changed.  StandardAnalyzer now implements [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which attempts to provide a non-language-specific text segmentation.